# uploading file to google cloud

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, multer

I'm trying to upload files to google cloud bucket using node js and express-file upload. So far when I upload a file itself gets uploaded to the bucket but the file size doesn't, which makes the image not working.

```
// uploading single image
const fileData = req.files.files
const creteFeed = await new Feed({
    feedby: req.user,
    feedTxt: txt,
    deleted: 0,
    feedReaction: 0,
    feedComment: 0,
    feedShare: 0,
    feedType: Feedtype,
})
const newFeed = await creteFeed.save()
if (newFeed) {
    const FeedMed = await new FeedMedia({
        feedby: req.user,
        feed_id: newFeed._id,
        feedMedia_type:fileData.mimetype,
        feedMedia_name: fileData.name,
        category:'feed',
        url: `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${fileData.name}`,
        deleted: 0
    })
    const newFeedMed = await FeedMed.save()
    if(newFeedMed){

        //  Create a new blob in the bucket and upload the file data.

        const blob = bucket.file(fileData.name);
        const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream();
        blobStream.on('finish', res => {

        });

        blobStream.on('finish', () => {
            // The public URL can be used to directly access the file via HTTP.
            const publicUrl = `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${blob.name}`

            res.status(200).send(publicUrl);
        });

        blobStream.end(fileData.buffer);
            // res.json('success')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you writing in your blobStream?

Comment: The first blobstream was a mistake the second is to get the URL of the uploaded file which it does but the file is working on googl bucket because no file size

Comment: Does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62666032/how-to-createwritestream-to-gcs?

Comment: Try adding some options to the create stream, like this: `blob.createWriteStream({ metadata: { contentType: file.mimetype } })` and removing the empty `.on('finish')`, let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks guys I just switch to multer instead of express-fileupload and it seems to work fine

Comment: @princerandy could you share what you have done to make it work in an answer to the question? This way it will be easier for other community member going through the same problem to replicate it.

Answer (score 1):

well after searching for a while i just had to switch to using multer

```
const gc = new Storage({
    keyFilename: Path.join(__dirname,process.env.gcBucket.jsonpath),
    projectId:process.env.gcBucketID
})

const bucket = gc.bucket(process.env.gcBucketname)
// Multer is required to process file uploads and make them available via
// req.files.
const multer = Multer({
    storage: Multer.memoryStorage(),
    limits: {
      fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024, // no larger than 5mb, you can change as needed.
    },
  });
```

```
Router.post('/pageFeed',multer.array('files'),authoriazation,async(req,res)=>{

  
    const { txt,Feedtype,feedby } = req.body


        // uploading multiple image
        if(req.files.length > 0){

            const creteFeed = await new Feed({
                feedby: feedby,
                feedTxt: txt,
                deleted: 0,
                feedReaction: 0,
                feedComment: 0,
                feedShare: 0,
                feedType: Feedtype,
            })
            const newFeed = await creteFeed.save()
            if(newFeed){
                for (newfile of req.files) {
                    const FeedMed = await new FeedMedia({
                        feed_id: newFeed._id,
                        feedby: feedby,
                        feedMedia_type:newfile.mimetype,
                        feedMedia_name:newfile.originalname,
                        category:'feed',
                        url: `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${newfile.originalname}`,
                        deleted:0
                    })
                    const newFeedMed = await FeedMed.save()
                    if(newFeedMed){
                        const blob = bucket.file(newfile.originalname);
                            const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream();
                           
                            blobStream.on('finish', () => {
                                // The public URL can be used to directly access the file via HTTP.
                                res.json({msg:'success'})
                            });
                        
                            blobStream.end(newfile.buffer);
                    }else{
                        res.json({error:'error uploading'})
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
        const creteFeed = await new Feed({
            feedby: feedby,
            feedTxt: txt,
            deleted: 0,
            feedReaction: 0,
            feedComment: 0,
            feedShare: 0,
            feedType: Feedtype,
        })
        const newFeed = await creteFeed.save()
        if(newFeed){
            res.json('success')
        }
        
    }

})
```