# Create archive from readable, add file and pipe to writable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, stream

The goal is to receive an archive form the client, add a file, and upload it to Cloud Storage without creating a temporary file. The client and the server both use the `archiver` library. The problem with the code below is that `file2.txt` does not get added to the archive.

Client:

```
import archiver from "archiver";

const archive = archiver("zip", {
    zlib: { level: 9 },
});

archive.append("string cheese!", { name: "file1.txt" });

await fetch(`/archive`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: archive,
});
```

Server:

```
import archiver from "archiver";
import { Storage } from "@google-cloud/storage";
import { Router } from "express";

const router = Router();
const storage = new Storage();

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const archive = archiver("zip", {
    zlib: { level: 9 },
  });

  const cloudFile = storage.bucket("archives").file("archive.zip");

  req.pipe(archive, {
    end: false,
  });

  archive.pipe(cloudFile.createWriteStream());

  req.on("end", async () => {
    archive.append("string cheese!", { name: "file2.txt" });
    archive.finalize();
    archive.end();
  });
});
```

Comment: The examples in this question might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62666032/8016720

Answer (score 0):

as i can see from the  [documentations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver)
they are using fs.createReadStream(file1) to reach out file system
however you can achieve this if you get Buffer from the received data

```
const multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer()

router.post("/", upload.none(), function (req, res, next) {

// append a file from buffer
const buffer = req.files[0].buffer
archive.append(buffer, { name: 'file3.txt' });
})
```

also a tip if you working in serverless env  most likely you don't have access
to file system to read, write and clean
but at some cases you have access to /temp  directory
it worth a quick search if this is the case

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it has nothing todo with my question. I don't want so save any files on disk (not even temporary). My request body is the archive (I don't use multer nor FormData) and to that I want to add a file "on the fly".